# Excel macro applying condition on multiple rows and columns

Tags: excel, automation, vba

I am performing Excel sheet macro automation wherein I have 3 columns say [`Name`, `Date`, `Work-Hours`] and many rows. What I need to do is, create a macro which iterates the `Date` column and notes all rows with same date and then adds Work-Hours for all those rows. Once total work-hour for a particular date is calculated, if it is greater than 9 hours, I'll have to highlight all rows corresponding to that date. Similarly, I have to do it for all the rows dates present in sheet.

```
For i = 2 To Rows.Count 'TO CHECK IF 9 HOURS ARE FILLED PER DAY 
  Do While DatePrevious = DateNext 
    hours = hours + Cells(i, 5) 
  Loop 
  If hours >= 9 Then 
    hours = 0 
  Else 
    Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 10 
    hours = 0 
  End If 
Next i
```

Comment: Because Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service you will need to show what you already tried. [Edit] your question, insert your code and ask a *specific* question to your code. Also read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: Hey, this is the script I am running :
****************************************************************************************
For i = 2 To Rows.Count
            
    'TO CHECK IF 9 HOURS ARE FILLED PER DAY
        Do While DatePrevious = DateNext
            hours = hours + Cells(i, 5)
        Loop
        If hours >= 9 Then
            hours = 0
        Else
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            hours = 0
        End If
        
    Next i

NOTE: I have defined all variables already.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments these are unreadable. Use the [edit] button as I told you.